# SQLAlchemy Filter On Relationship Not Working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I have two classes:

- Trade
- TradeItem

One Trade has multiple TradeItems.  It's a simple 1-to-many relationship.

**Trade**

```
class Trade(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'trade'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name= Column(String)

    trade_items = relationship('TradeItem',
                            back_populates='trade')
```

**TradeItem**

```
class TradeItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'trade_item'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    location = Column(String)
    trade_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('trade.id'))

    trade = relationship('Trade',
                            back_populates='trade_items')
```

**Filtering**

```
session.query(Trade).filter(Trade.name == trade_name and TradeItem.location == location)
```

I want to get the Trade object by name and only those Trade Items where the location matches the given location name.

So if there is a trade object:  Trade(name='Trade1') and it has 3 items:
TradeItem(location='loc1'),TradeItem(location='loc2'),TradeItem(location='loc2')

Then the query should return only my target trade items for the trade:

```
session.query(Trade).filter(Trade.name == 'Trade1' and TradeItem.location == 'loc1').first()
```

Then I expect the query to return Trade with name Trade1 but only one Trade item populated with location as loc1

But when I get the trade object, it has all of the Trade Items and it completely ignores the filter condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [contains_eager](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#explicit-join-eagerload) option to to load only the child rows selected by the filter.

Note that to create a `WHERE ... AND ...` filter you can use sqlalchemy.and_,  or chain `filter` or `filter_by` methods, but using Python's logical `and` will not work as expected.

```py
from sqlalchemy import orm, and_

trade = (session.query(Trade)
         .filter(and_(Trade.name == 'Trade1', TradeItem.location == 'loc1'))
         .options(orm.contains_eager(Trade.trade_items))
         .first())
```

The query generates this SQL :

```sql
SELECT trade_item.id AS trade_item_id, trade_item.location AS trade_item_location, trade_item.trade_id AS trade_item_trade_id, trade.id AS trade_id, trade.name AS trade_name 
FROM trade 
JOIN trade_item ON trade.id = trade_item.trade_id 
WHERE trade.name = 'trade1' AND trade_item.location = 'loc1'
 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Question - if one TradeItem has multiple TradeItemTypes (each with a name property) and I wanted to only return Trade/TradeItem for a given type name- how will I do it?  Do i need to do .options(orm.contains_eager(TradeItem.trade_item_types))